# How to restrict my app which has option to authenticate a dropbox account to access the External dropbox app

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I have an app and my app has Dropbox sdk integrated. The problem is- I also have the Dropbox app installed in my device. So, whenever, I try to authenticate my app's dropbox, it redirects me to the account the Dropbox app has.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to stop my app from going to the external dropbox app while authenticating.

Answer (score 0):

[The official Objective-C SDK for Dropbox API v2](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c) doesn't offer an option to not use the installed official Dropbox app for the authorization flow, but I'll pass this along as a feature request.